# Unable to load file or assembly mongocrypt

Tags: c#, mongodb, hangfire

> **System.BadImageFormatException**: 'Could not load file or assembly 'mongocrypt' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.'

I have a project that runs Hangfire 1.7.5 with MongoDB 2.9.1.0. This project is used as a backend engine to perform various types of work.

In order to create endpoints for outside systems to call this engine, we have another project that uses the same versions of Hangfire and MongoDB to connect and pass in the jobs for processing.

I upgraded Hangfire and Mongo to the latest versions, 1.7.9 and 2.10.1.0 respectively in all the projects that were using these dlls. Using Visual Studio, when I run the web projects, I keep getting the above mentioned error. I get these like 4 to 5 times before the ASP.Net site loads up and allows me to access anything I need, including the data that is accessed via MongoDB. Just an inconvenience but still an exception when loading project.

I know that architecture of the CPUs might cause the System.BadImageFormatException but nothing in that sense has been changed. I am running everything on .net 4.6.1 and everything continues to run on AnyCPU configuration. If I change all these projects to x64 or x86, one or the other thing stops working. mongocrypt error continues to occur regardless of the CPU architecture.

I cant find anything on google or SO regarding mongocrypt. Any ideas?

Comment: Issue still exists with v2.10.3 ...  Exception generated with v2.10.x is System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly (even though its there, installed, verified) mongocrypt.dll

Comment: I'm getting this error with v2.10.4 while I'm debugging through IIS Express (2019 Pro), but everything works on my test server running fat IIS. Interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to us.
It appears that in v2.10.0 a new dependency library was introduced libmongocrypt
that causes this error.

Try to go back to v2.9.3 to workaround this issue until it is fixed by mongodb programmers.

[mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb)[libmongocrypt](/questions/tagged/libmongocrypt)[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

Comment: It does solve the problem if I take each project i have with mongodb on it to 2.9.3. I guess take this as an answer and wait for next release !!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when upgrading and in my case it seemed to have actually been caused by a different package, WebActivator, which attempted to load up all the dlls in the bin folder. It failed to load up mongocrypt.dll because it wasn't a .net dll as expected and so gave the error listed in the question. The version of WebActivator that had the problem was 1.0.0. The latest version 1.5.3 doesn't cause this error.

To be clear in my case at least this was *not* a problem with the mongocrypt package that later versions of the mongo c# drivers includes but triggered by it because mongocrypt includes a non-.net DLL that caused a different package to error!